# What exactly does '#[derive(Debug)]' mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

What exactly does `#[derive(Debug)]` mean? Does it have something to do with `'a`? For example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: u8
}
```

Comment: It's an attribute that provides a basic implementation of the Debug trait for the following struct. Have a read through https://rustbyexample.com/trait/derive.html . (It has nothing to do with the life-time `a'`.)

Comment: Just keep reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch05-02-example-structs.html).

Comment: https://rustbyexample.com/trait/derive.html moved to https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/trait/derive.html as of 2022-10-17.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`#[...]` is an [attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/attribute.html) on `struct Person`. `derive(Debug)` asks the compiler to [auto-generate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/trait/derive.html) a suitable implementation of the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) trait, which provides the result of `{:?}` in something like `format!("Would the real {:?} please stand up!", Person { name: "John", age: 8 });`.

You can see what the compiler did by executing `cargo +nightly rustc -- -Zunstable-options --pretty=expanded`. In your example, the compiler will add something like

```
#[automatically_derived]
#[allow(unused_qualifications)]
impl <'a> ::std::fmt::Debug for Person<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, __arg_0: &mut ::std::fmt::Formatter) -> ::std::fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            Person { name: ref __self_0_0, age: ref __self_0_1 } => {
                let mut builder = __arg_0.debug_struct("Person");
                let _ = builder.field("name", &&(*__self_0_0));
                let _ = builder.field("age", &&(*__self_0_1));
                builder.finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to your code. As such an implementation is suitable for almost all uses, the `derive` saves you from writing it by hand.

The `'a` is a [lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime.html)-parameter for the type `Person`; that is, there (could be) several versions of `Person`, each with its own concrete lifetime, which will be named `'a`. This lifetime-parameter is used to qualify (generically) the reference in the field `name`, a reference to some value of type `str`. This is necessary because the compiler will need some information on how long this reference will be valid (to the ultimate goal that the reference to the value of `name` does not become invalid while a value of type `Person` is still in use).

Comment: Why doesn't age need a lifetime specifier and why does the compiler generate code such as `&&(*__self_0_0)`? What's the point of "&&" and why does it dereference it inside the parenthesis?