# Why does the Debug formatter expose private struct fields?

Tags: rust, formatting, private

I am using `{:?}` to print the value of a `Breakfast` struct. It includes the private field `seasonal_fruit`. Why I am able to print it with `println!`?

```
mod back_of_house {
    #[derive(Debug)]

    pub struct Breakfast {
        pub toast: String,
        seasonal_fruit: String, // NOT PUB !!!
    }

    impl Breakfast {
        pub fn summer(toast: &str) -> Breakfast {
            Breakfast {
                toast: String::from(toast),
                seasonal_fruit: String::from("Peaches"),
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn eat_at_restaurant() {
    // Order a breakfast in the summer with Rye toast
    let mut meal = back_of_house::Breakfast::summer("Rye");

    // Change our mind about what bread we'd like
    meal.toast = String::from("Wheat");

    println!("I'd like {} toast please", meal.toast);

    println!("I'd like {:?} toast please", meal);
}

fn main() {
    eat_at_restaurant()
}
```

Comment: `eat_at_restaurant` is not using the private field directly; it calls a public method (from the derived `Debug` trait), which can access private fields.  That's the point of privacy and encapsulation - the ways private fields can be used are defined in the public interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't it include private fields? When you *debug* things, you usually want to have access to as much information as possible. When you connect to the running process with a debugger, you have access to the same information, for example.

If you are actually asking **how** can it access private fields, then that's because the implementation of the `Debug` trait for this struct is located in a scope that has access to the private fields of the struct (in the same module, in this case).

If you are actually asking how to **prevent** it from showing certain fields, then you can implement `Debug` yourself for a type and control exactly what is included. This often uses methods like [`Formatter::debug_struct`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.debug_struct) to produce nicely formatted output.

See also:

- [What exactly does '#[derive(Debug)]' mean in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46388386/155423)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, also time, effort, knowledge, reaction.